# Checkbox go to another view controller objective c

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to create a checkbox button, when the user click on that button it will check in and take him to another view controller. below is my checkbox code, can anyone help how can send the user to the other view controller? 
Note I am using a storybored. 
The header

```
IBOutlet UIButton *Checkbox;
BOOL checked;
(IBAction)CheckboxAction:(id)sender;
```

and here is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad : (BOOL)animated
        {NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            checked = [defaults boolForKey:@"boxIsChecked"];
            [self checkTheBox];}


-(void) checkTheBox
    {
    if (!checked) 
        {[Checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];}
            else if (checked) 
            {[Checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBoxMarked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];}
        }


- (IBAction)CheckboxAction:(id)sender 
        {NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

            if (!checked) 
            {[Checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBoxMarked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                checked = YES;
                [defaults setBool:checked forKey:@"boxIsChecked"];}
            else if (checked) 
            {[Checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                checked = NO;
                [defaults setBool:checked forKey:@"boxIsChecked"];}

            [defaults synchronize];
        }
```

Comment: How are you looking to present your other ViewController? Modal, NavigationController, Segue?  It seems like you can just put it in the `checkboxAction` method.

Comment: @Logan This is my concern, I usually do this by using NavigationController but this time its kinda of different since I am dealing with an Action button. Please advice.

Comment: There is nothing different, just perform a 'push' to the destination ViewController if you are using a navigation controller. Other wise you can use modal presentation. Incase you are using storyboard you can perform segue.

Comment: I added an answer, you will have to adjust your instantiation if you're using storyboards or a xib.

Comment: @somexyz I would do that but as I mentioned also if you took a look to the code you will find that when the user click on the button it will check in "it will show another checked button". After that action I want the program to move the user to another view controller, to another page.

Comment: @logan Thanks I added a comment, and I am sorry I forgot to mention that I am using a storyboards not xib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)CheckboxAction:(id)sender {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if (!checked) {
        [Checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBoxMarked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        checked = YES;
        [defaults setBool:checked forKey:@"boxIsChecked"];
    }
    else if (checked) {
        [Checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        checked = NO;
        [defaults setBool:checked forKey:@"boxIsChecked"];
    }

    [defaults synchronize];

    // ADD THIS
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    YourViewController *yourVC = (YourViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourViewControllerIdentifier"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:yourVC animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: yourviewcontroller you mean the one that I want to transfer the user too? or the one that I am in already? cause when I use the view controller that I want to be transferred it give me an error, note I already import the .h class in the view controller

Comment: It should be the controller you want to go to.  Can you tell me what error?

Comment: this is the error I get **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'MainStoryboard' in bundle NSBundle </Users/Lolieta/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1-64/Applications/E979E73B-6991-4E9F-B478-0C610BDD0DC6/myapp.app> (loaded)'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: What is the name of your storyboard?  It's automatically named "MainStoryboard".  Just replace that with whatever yours is named.

Comment: I figured it out, change `@"MainStoryboard"` to `@"Main"`.

Comment: There is no error but its not moving me to the other view controller :(

Comment: Sounds like something else is going on here.  Have you made sure that yourViewController's class is connected to it in storyboard?

Comment: Can you host your project on github?

Comment: yes my view controller is assign to the class, but I think the problem is with the code, something is blocked and its not letting the part "Where he move to the new controller" process. I am really beginner, but I will send you the code via Email, is that okay ?

Comment: Sure, I can take a look at it quick.

Comment: please check your Email,